# Error when try to customize font in xamarin.android

Tags: android, fonts, xamarin, customization

I used xamarin.android for develop app, I tried to customize font with code:

```
 Typeface myfont = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Context.Assets, "fonts/KhmerOS.ttf");
```

but when I built, it error as shown bellow:

```
Error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Android.Content.Context.Assets.get' (CS0120)
```

please help me,

Best Regard
Buntha

Answer (score 4):

This may be the late reply but might help someone with the same issue. Set BuilAction to Android Asset for font file. (Right click on fontfile->BuildAction select AndroidAsset)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Application.Context.Assets, "fonts/KhmerOS.ttf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace App3.Droid.Debug
{
    class MyLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var label = (TextView)Control;
        Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "your font name.otf/ttf");
        label.Typeface = font;
    }
}
}
```

Note: Put Fonts to Assets and set property "Build Action on AndroidAsset and Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always"

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code as

```
Typeface custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font name.ttf");
tx.setTypeface(custom_font);
```