# Change typeface of formatted text in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a label with formatted text and I wanna change its font style(I mean typeface). 
I tried using Custom Label Rendering( like doing it for the normal text) ,but it is not getting reflected. 
My doubt is whether we can change typeface of formatted text (since it is working fine for text (not formatted text) of label).

This is my .xaml file code

```
<Label x:Name = "invosTitle" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.Row = "0" Grid.ColumnSpan = "3"  HorizontalOptions = "CenterAndExpand">
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <FormattedString.Spans>
                    <Span Text = "abcd"  ForegroundColor = "White" ></Span>
                    <Span Text = "   "></Span>
                    <Span Text = "efgh" ForegroundColor = "Gray"></Span>
                </FormattedString.Spans>
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

and CustomLabelRenderer code is

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender , PropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
    var label = (TextView)Control; 
    Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Forms.Context.Assets,  "Fonts/microsoftjhengheibold.otf");
    label.Typeface = font;
    label.SetTypeface (font, TypefaceStyle.Bold);
}
```

Comment: Please format your post correctly. And you didn't show your .xaml file nor your CustomLabelRender code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307094/error-when-try-to-customize-font-in-xamarin-android/29410974#29410974

See my answer maybe its help

Comment: Just add FormattedString to a Label **at runtime**. This [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121135/span-label-underline-is-not-working-on-xamarin-ios) helps me to solve mine.

Answer (score 2):

When using the FormattedString element, you can change the typeface of each `Span` individually with the `FontFamily` attribute. You don't need a custom label renderer to achieve this.

```
<Span Text="abcd"  
      ForegroundColor="White" 
      FontFamily="Helvetica" />
```

This is documented in the [Xamarin "Working with fonts"](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/fonts/) documentation.

Comment: Thank you..Daniel.I am aware of this.But for some reasons I should not update Xamarin.forms package to 1.3 (I am using 1.2). So I am asking if I can do it using CustomLabelRendering and typeface. :-)

Comment: Can you please tell me if specifying font family works on Android also

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone needs to keep the same font and just change the spans color here's the code:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (Label), typeof (LabelCustomRenderer))]
namespace YourNamespace
{

public class LabelCustomRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        Init ();
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged (sender, e);
        if (e.PropertyName == Label.FontFamilyProperty.PropertyName) {
            Init ();
        }
    }

    void Init(){
        if (Control != null) {
            var label = (CustomLabel)Element;
            if (label.FontName != null) {
                if (label.FormattedText != null) {
                    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder ();

                    foreach (Span span in label.FormattedText.Spans) {
                        ssb.Append (span.Text);
                        ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan (span.ForegroundColor.ToAndroid ());
                        ssb.SetSpan (foregroundColorSpan, ssb.Length () - span.Text.Length, ssb.Length (), SpanTypes.ExclusiveExclusive);
                    }
                    Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Forms.Context.Assets, "Fonts/" + label.FontFamily);
                    Control.Typeface = font;
                    Control.TextSize = (float)label.FontSize;
                    Control.SetText (ssb, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                } else {
                    Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Forms.Context.Assets, "Fonts/" + label.FontFamily);
                    Control.Typeface = font;
                    Control.TextSize = (float)label.FontSize;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```