# Custom Font in Xamarin.Forms Label with FormattedString

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have created a custom LabelRenderer in my Android app to apply a custom font in a Xamarin Android app (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/).

Everything works great for a normal label with the content added to the .Text property. However, if I create a label using .FormattedText property, the custom font is not applied.

Anyone have success doing this? An option, since I'm just stacking lines of different sized text, is to use separate label controls for each, but I'd prefer to use a formatted string if possible.

Here's the guts of my custom renderer:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (gbrLabel), typeof (gbrLabelRenderer))]

public class gbrLabelRenderer: LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        var label = (TextView)Control;
        Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset (Forms.Context.Assets, "Lobster-Regular.ttf");
        label.Typeface = font;
    }
}
```

And here's my simple label control... all it does is apply the font to iOS, and leaves applying the font for Android up to the custom renderer.

```cs
public class gbrLabel: Label
{
    public gbrLabel ()
    {
        Device.OnPlatform (
            iOS: () => {
                FontFamily = "Lobster-Regular";
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium,this);
            }
    }
}
```

Works fine for labels with just the .Text property... but not for labels with the .FormattedText property.

Should I keep digging, or just stack my labels since that's an option in this case?

Here's an example of the various ways I've tried this in the Formatted text, since that was requested:

```cs
var fs = new FormattedString ();
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { 
    Text = string.Format("LINE 1\n",Title), 
    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large,typeof(Label))
});
fs.Spans.Add (new Span { 
    Text = string.Format ("LINE 2\n"), 
    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large,typeof(Label)) * 2,
    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
    FontFamily = "Lobster-Regular"
});
fs.Spans.Add (new Span {
    Text = string.Format ("LINE 3\n"),
    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Medium,typeof(Label)),
    FontFamily = "Lobster-Regular.ttf"
});

gbrLabel lblContent = new gbrLabel {
    FormattedText = fs
}
```

None of these (the first should be set by the default class / renderer, and the second 2 are variations of including the font in a span definition itself) work on Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change typeface of formatted text in Xamarin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407417/change-typeface-of-formatted-text-in-xamarin)

Comment: True, it's very similar... no one has given a good answer to that question, though. I've never asked a dupe before - can I move my question over there  to freshen things up?

Comment: What are you missing from that answer? You can set the font for each span. Or is your goal, to set the font in the background for all Labels,so that you don't have to set it manually?

Comment: That works fine for iOS, but you can't set the font in the spans (or anywhere in Xamarin.Forms for that matter) for Android. You need the custom renderer, but it only seems to work when you you use the .Text property, not the .FormattedText property, even if you want ALL of the text to be the same font, just different sizes.

As a side note, I DO want a base font for all labels, but that's easy enough to accomplish. The issue here is entirely focused on the .FormattedText property and setting fonts there for the Android platform.

Comment: Can you please show how you set the FormattedText and what the formatted text is?

Comment: I added the formatted text section to the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Note:** Android and iOS issues have been summarized on a blog post: [smstuebe.de/2016/04/03/formattedtext.xamrin.forms/](http://smstuebe.de/2016/04/03/formattedtext.xamrin.forms/)

---

The font is set as long as you do not set `FontSize` or `FontAttributes`. So I had the look at the implementation and found that the `FormattedText` is trying to load the font like the default renderer which doesn't work on Android.

The android formatting system works very similar to that one of Xamarin.Forms. It's using spans to define text attributes. The renderer is adding a `FontSpan` for every `Span` with a custom font, size or attribute. Unfortunately, the `FontSpan`class is a private inner class of `FormattedStringExtensions` so we have to deal with reflections.

Our Renderer is updating the `Control.TextFormatted` on initialization and when the `FormattedText` property changes. In the update method, we get all `FontSpan`s and replace them with our `CustomTypefaceSpan`.

**Renderer**

```cs
public class FormattedLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    private static readonly Typeface Font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "LobsterTwo-Regular.ttf");
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        Control.Typeface = Font;
        UpdateFormattedText();
    }

    private void UpdateFormattedText()
    {
        if (Element.FormattedText != null)
        {
            var extensionType = typeof(FormattedStringExtensions);
            var type = extensionType.GetNestedType("FontSpan", BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var ss = new SpannableString(Control.TextFormatted);
            var spans = ss.GetSpans(0, ss.ToString().Length, Class.FromType(type));
            foreach (var span in spans)
            {
                var start = ss.GetSpanStart(span);
                var end = ss.GetSpanEnd(span);
                var flags = ss.GetSpanFlags(span);
                var font = (Font)type.GetProperty("Font").GetValue(span, null);
                ss.RemoveSpan(span);
                var newSpan = new CustomTypefaceSpan(Control, font);
                ss.SetSpan(newSpan, start, end, flags);
            }
            Control.TextFormatted = ss;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == Label.FormattedTextProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            UpdateFormattedText();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure, why you introduced a new element type `gbrLabel`, but as long as you only wan't to change the renderer, you don't have to create a custom element. You can replace the renderer of the default element:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(FormattedLabelRenderer))]
```

**CustomTypefaceSpan**

```cs
public class CustomTypefaceSpan : MetricAffectingSpan
{
    private readonly Typeface _typeFace;
    private readonly Typeface _typeFaceBold;
    private readonly Typeface _typeFaceItalic;
    private readonly Typeface _typeFaceBoldItalic;
    private readonly TextView _textView;
    private Font _font;

    public CustomTypefaceSpan(TextView textView, Font font)
    {
        _textView = textView;
        _font = font;
        // Note: we are ignoring _font.FontFamily (but thats easy to change)
        _typeFace = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "LobsterTwo-Regular.ttf");
        _typeFaceBold = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "LobsterTwo-Bold.ttf");
        _typeFaceItalic = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "LobsterTwo-Italic.ttf");
        _typeFaceBoldItalic = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "LobsterTwo-BoldItalic.ttf");
    }

    public override void UpdateDrawState(TextPaint paint)
    {
        ApplyCustomTypeFace(paint);
    }

    public override void UpdateMeasureState(TextPaint paint)
    {
        ApplyCustomTypeFace(paint);
    }

    private void ApplyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint)
    {
        var tf = _typeFace;

        if (_font.FontAttributes.HasFlag(FontAttributes.Bold) && _font.FontAttributes.HasFlag(FontAttributes.Italic))
        {
            tf = _typeFaceBoldItalic;
        }
        else if (_font.FontAttributes.HasFlag(FontAttributes.Bold))
        {
            tf = _typeFaceBold;
        }
        else if (_font.FontAttributes.HasFlag(FontAttributes.Italic))
        {
            tf = _typeFaceItalic;
        }

        paint.SetTypeface(tf);
        paint.TextSize = TypedValue.ApplyDimension(ComplexUnitType.Sp, _font.ToScaledPixel(), _textView.Resources.DisplayMetrics);
    }
}
```

Our Custom `CustomTypefaceSpan`is similar to the `FontSpan` of Xamarin.Forms, but is loading the custom fonts and can load different fonts for different `FontAttributes`.

The result is a nice colorful Text :)
[image]

Comment: The line: `var spans = ss.GetSpans(0, ss.ToString().Length, Class.FromType(type));`

Is causing me an error while compiling: 

`[...]/FormattedLabelRenderer.cs(60,60): Error CS0176: Static member Java.Lang.Class.FromType(System.Type) cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead (CS0176) (GbrEvents.Droid)`. I'm trying to find out what exactly this means... maybe I'm missing a using statement?

Comment: `Class` is also a property of the Renderer because it inherits from Java.Lang.Object. Can you try to use the full qualified name `Java.Lang.Class.FromType`? or use `using Java.Lang;`

Comment: I already tried using Java.Lang; ... didn't help. Adding the fully qualified reference did the trick, though... Works PERFECT! I probably had another using statement in the class causing it get confused. We're good to go, time to play with fonts, sizes, and colors.

Comment: I am currently summing it up in a blog post... found some issues on iOS as well. So don't over exceed your playing ^^

Comment: If you are interested, the blog post is now published: smstuebe.de/2016/04/03/formattedtext.xamrin.forms/

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe, haha we meet again. I am having the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743751/do-custom-fonts-work-for-formatted-string . I guess I have to follow your snippets in your blog?

Comment: Just add FormattedString to a Label **at runtime**. This [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121135/span-label-underline-is-not-working-on-xamarin-ios) helps me to solve mine.