# Span Label underline is not working on Xamarin iOS

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, datatrigger, underline

I'm using a Label with Spans, one of them is a link and I want to add an underline style, I'm using `<Span Text="Link url" TextDecorations="Underline" />` but it is not working in iOS with `"Xamarin.Forms" Version="5.0.0.2401"`.

I have tried to add an effect but all the properties needs to be set again
(Styles, touch events, etc...).

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Text 1"/>
            <Span Text="Text 2"/>
            <Span Text="Click to open Link" TextDecorations="Underline">
                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding lINKCommand}"/>
                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

In some time Xamarin forms needs to fix it, meanwhile I want to apply a small temporal fix.

Answer (score 4):

I discovered that it works when set `TextType` property to `Html` in the `Label` at runtime.

So I had to create a data trigger and use a data binding to set when all data is loaded.

```
<Label>
    <Label.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Label" Binding="{Binding IsBusy}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="TextType" Value="Html" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Label.Triggers>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="Text 1"/>
            <Span Text="Text 2"/>
            <Span Text="Click to open Link" TextDecorations="Underline">
                <Span.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding lINKCommand}"/>
                </Span.GestureRecognizers>
            </Span>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Comment: This runtime concept helps me fix my issue of showing text in new line in iOS app.

Comment: This solution works great for showing underline spans inside my label.. but it seems that the tap gesture recognizer isn't working. My link command never gets hit. I tried as well using the Tapped event but still doesn't work. My code looks exactly the same as yours. Are your commands working correctly?

Comment: Yeah the tap command works good, are you still facing the same issue?

Answer (score 4):

The TextType.Html trick is working. I can see the underline, but it my case it brakes the TapGestureRecognizer command. So setting the Label on Html text type and after back to Text text type solves also this.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MyLabel.TextType = TextType.Html;
    MyLabel.TextType = TextType.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have also discovered that it works when You set FontSize in Label at runtime.

Comment: Yeah it is weird, just I'm waiting for Xamarin Forms to fix it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Span stopped to display text decorations when I have updated iOS SDK from 16.0 to 16.2. Xamarin.Forms version 5.0.0.2545 and 5.0.0.2578 does not fix this problem. My solution for that is to replace Span with simple Label, then text decorations works. Little extra work.

Comment: Did you submit an issue to Xamarin, and can you link to this?

Comment: I submitted a bug: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/15749